# How to make a ternary contour plot with Python Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot a function defined on a simplex. Apparently, you can [do it very nicely using the Matlab API](https://plot.ly/matlab/ternary-plots/).

[image]

But I cannot figure out how to do this using the Python API. The reference has a section named [Ternary Contour Plots in Python](https://plot.ly/python/ternary-contour/) but it does not plot a numeric function, but a function mapping the simplex to a given discrete set.

I tried to emulate the Matlab code:

```
import plotly as py

A = [0, .2, .2, .2, 0, .6, .75, .9, 0, 1, .8, .3]
B = [1, .2, .4, .1, 0, .4, .05, 0, .8, 0, .05, .3]
C = [0, .6, .4, .7, 1, 0, .2, .1, .2, 0, .15, .4]
Z = [.1, .5, .1, .2, 1, .8, .4, 0, .1, .6, 1, .7]

trace = {
    "type": 'scatterternary',
    "carpet": 'scattercontour',
    "a": A,
    "b": B,
    "c": C,
    "z": Z
}

layout = {
    'title': 'Simple Ternary Contour Plot with Python'
}

figure = dict(data=[trace], layout=layout)
py.offline.plot(figure, validate=False)
```

But I get this plot instead:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still interested, [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/empet/Ternary-contour-plot/blob/master/Plotly-ternary-contour-plot.ipynb) is a Jupyter Notebook to see how to generate a Plotly ternary contour plot.

Answer (score -1):

One workaround is possible if you can generate the data whose contours you want to plot for arbitrary proportions. In this case, you can generate the (x, y) data on a mesh, map them to barycentric coordinates, and compute the value z. Then you can use the non-ternary plots like contour or surface.

Here is an example that plots the density function of the Dirichlet distribution:

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np


def compute_in_barycentric_coordinates(a, b, c):
    epsilon = 1e-6
    if 0.0 < a < 1.0 and 0.0 < b < 1.0 and 0.0 < c < 1.0 and abs(a + b + c - 1.0) < epsilon:
        return pow(a, 2) * pow(b, 1.5) * pow(c, 1.8)
    return None


x_data = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
y_data = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
z_data = []
f = 1.0 / pow(3.0, 0.5)
for y in y_data:
    next_slice = []
    for x in x_data:
        a = 1 - x - f*y
        b = x - f*y
        c = 2*f*y
        z = compute_in_barycentric_coordinates(a, b, c)
        next_slice.append(z)
    z_data.append(next_slice)


data = [
    go.Contour(
        x=x_data,
        y=y_data,
        z=z_data,
    )
]


py.offline.plot(data)
```

[image]

However, it is still a workaround, so if you have a better idea, I will be very happy to hear from you.